# Execute environment file in ansible

Tags: ansible, environment-variables

I am trying to setup a playbook which will execute the env file of a service before running the command to stop the service.
Note that **stop** or **start** service command will only work after execute that env file.

The command to execute the env file is `. ./.env_file_name` or `ksh .env_file_name`

I am not able to execute the file using the above command in command module and shell module.

1. How to execute the above env file in ansible ?
2. How to run the stop command after executing the env file ?

Comment: Can you attach the playbook or at least the task that is problematic ?

Comment: @MarcABOUCHACRA I have to develop playbook to read and set the environment variables present in the file and to run the command with those environment. I dont have playbook to resolve this

Answer (score 1):

If env file contains some environment variables that you need to set before running stop, then you can read the file, store results in a variable, then use [environment](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_environment.html) keyword to provide them to the task, that actually stops the service.

Alternatively, you can add multiple commands in shell module at once, like so:

```
- name: Example for a shell module
  shell:
    cmd: |
      ./.env_file_name
      ./stop.sh (insert command to stop the service here)
```

Comment: One other IMO better solution would be to register your service in systemd with its own specific environment and then use the systemd ansible module to control it.

Comment: @K. Alexander Thank you for your answer. May I Know how to read and set all the environment variables from the environment file. Would you please provide the playbook task to get this done